# Reflection and Transmission at oblique incidence Griffiths

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, reflection

I’m working through Griffiths E&M and on page 408 he gives the boundary conditions for oblique incidence. I’ve spent an hour trying to understand how he goes from the boundary condition 
$$\epsilon_1(\textbf{E}_{0I} + \textbf{E}_{0R})_z = \epsilon_2(\textbf{E}_{0T})_z$$ to $$\epsilon_1(-E_{0I}\sin{\theta_I}+E_{0R}\sin{\theta_R})=\epsilon_2(-E_{0T}\sin{\theta_T})$$

And I must say I’m miffed. Any help greatly appreciated...[image]

Comment: Please let us know what's got you miffed.   Perhaps fill in the steps that you would take, and show how you get a different answer.   It's hard to help when we don't know what the sticking point is.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that your confusion has to do with not noticing or misinterpreting the subscript "z" in the first equation. It means take the z component of the vector, hence the $\sin(\theta)$ on both sides (the opposite signs on the left side have to do with directions).

If that was not your confusion you will have to be more specific about what it is that confuses you.

Comment: And did Griffiths just assume the directions? How did he know where to put a '-' and where to put a '+'... Look at the diagram... What if I flip E_I and leave other Es unchanged or maybe change E_T and leave other Es unchanged? What told Griffiths that that won't be the case? Is it as if he already knows that the incident and the transmitted waves should be in phase... Did he just use the ideas from the "normal incidence" case as a motivation for such a construction? Please explain...